# Different examples based on inheritance with Open API 3

Tags: spring-boot, inheritance, springdoc

I want to make different examples in Swagger for parent attributes.
Is there any simple way to achieve this one?

```
class Link {
    @Schema(description = "Next link", example = "http://")
    private String next;
    @Schema(description = "Previous link", example = "http://")
    private String previous;
}
class Sample<T> {
    private List<T> items;
    private Link _href;
}
class SampleA extends Sample<A> {}
class SampleB extends Sample<B> {}
```

example of SampleA are

- next: abc.com
- previous: abc.com?page=2

example of SampleB are

- next: xyz.com
- previous: xyz.com?page=2

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample working code for inheritance:

```
class Link {
    @Schema(description = "Next link", example = "http://")
    @JsonProperty
    private String next;

    @Schema(description = "Previous link", example = "http://")
    @JsonProperty
    private String previous;
}

@Schema(subTypes = {SampleA.class, SampleB.class})
class Sample<T> {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<T> items;
    @JsonProperty
    private Link _href;
}

@Schema(allOf = Sample.class)
class SampleA extends Sample {}

@Schema(allOf = Sample.class)
class SampleB extends Sample {}


@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/getA")
    SampleA getA() {
        return new SampleA();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getB")
    SampleB getAB() {
        return new SampleB();
    }
}
```

And this is the resulting OpenAPI Spec:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: OpenAPI definition
  version: v0
servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8080'
    description: Generated server url
paths:
  /getA:
    get:
      tags:
        - hello-controller
      operationId: getA
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SampleA'
  /getB:
    get:
      tags:
        - hello-controller
      operationId: getAB
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SampleB'
components:
  schemas:
    Link:
      type: object
      properties:
        next:
          type: string
          description: Next link
          example: 'http://'
        previous:
          type: string
          description: Previous link
          example: 'http://'
    Sample:
      type: object
      properties:
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
        _href:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Link'
    SampleA:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sample'
    SampleB:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sample'
```